# ModalDialog blocking in java

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I have a long task which is running and I am popping up a modaldialog with `MainUI.modalDialog.setVisible(true);` which has a ProgressBar. However I do observe that it is blocking the process. How do I popup the Dialog without blocking whatever is running in my frame?

Comment: are you running your process outside the EDT? for example in SwingWorker?

Comment: Short answer is, you don't.  Modal dialogs block the execution of the code from the point that the dialog is made visible.  Can you expand on what it is you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

That is the modal dialogs behavior. The options are that you either don't display it as modal or you display it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should whatever is running in your frame into another Thread, in case it is not GUI code. Also you could run the modal dialog in a separate GUI thread.

Comment: How do you run something on a separate GUI thread?  Swing is a single threaded environment (your first part of answer is right)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

"In user interface design, a modal window is a child window that **requires users to interact with it before they can return** to operating the parent application, **thus preventing the workflow** on the application main window. Modal windows are often called heavy windows or modal dialogs because the window is often used to display a dialog box."

Solution: Do not use a Modal Window.